# label change text every x seconds c# array

Tags: .net, timer, label

I have a label on a form and I want to change the label every 3 seconds with a value from a string[] array. I want to rotate through the string array endlessly to update the label.

```
    public void rotateMarqueText(string text)
    {
        string[] result = text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        newsPostCount = result.Count();
        new Task(() =>
        {
            foreach (var a in result)
            {
                DisplayText(a);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return true;
            }

        }
   ).Start();

    }



    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;


    private void DisplayText(string x)
    {
        marqueText.Text = x;
    }
```

It doesnt rotate through the list

Comment: Whats your question, what have you tried, and what is it exactly that you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public void rotateMarqueText(string text)

    {
        string[] result = "test\nme\n\please\n".Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        new Task(() =>
        {
            int i = result.Count();
            while (true)
            {
                i++;
                if (i > result.Count()) i = 0;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => DisplayText(result[i])));
                });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    private void DisplayText(string x)
    {
        marqueText.Text = x;
        marqueText.Refresh();
    }
```

Ok got it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

oK.... can you documentate about THREADS ... I'm very shure that you will find the answer ... From wath i can remember you need to start a thread like this :

```
Thread myTh = new Thread();
while(....) {  //put a condition...how much to run the thread ex: untill you pres a button
myTh.Sleep(2000);  // sleeps for 2 sec 
label.text = your value from array[i]
}
```

have a nice day ...